# Android onDetach() not called when I replace fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I have two fragments (FRAGMENT_1, FRAGMENT_2). FRAGMENT_1 is running a timer and when I open FRAGMENT_2, I want FRAGMENT_1 to keep running it.

**FRAGMENT_1 in onCreate():**

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    FRAGMENT_1 fragment1= new FRAGMENT_1();
    fragment1.setRetainInstance(true);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment1, FRAGMENT_1_TAG)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
}
```

This is my navigation between fragments:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String fragTag = "";
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.nav_frag_1:
            //this method returns
            //getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()
            //.contains(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag))
            if (isFragmentCreated(FRAGMENT_1_TAG)) {
                fragment = getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_1_TAG);
            } else {
                fragment = new FRAGMENT_1();
            }
            fragTag = FRAGMENT_1_TAG;
            break;

        case R.id.nav_frag_2:
            fragment = new FRAGMENT_2();
            fragTag = FRAGMENT_2_TAG;
            break;

        case R.id.nav_settings:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

    }
    if (fragment != null && !fragment.isVisible()) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment, fragTag);
        if (fragment.getTag().equals(FRAGMENT_1_TAG)){
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

When I navigate between these fragments, FRAGMENT_2 doesn't call `onDetach()` therefore it is not removed, but if I remove the following piece of code:

```
if (fragment.getTag().equals(TIMER_FRAGMENT_TAG)){
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
}
```

then FRAGMENT_2 calls `onDetach()` and then gets removed. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 14):

In Fragment lifecycle methods for destroying calls with this turn 
*onPause() -> onStop() -> onDestroyView() -> onDestroy() -> onDetach()*.

`addToBackStack(null)` method adds fragment to backStack, i.e it saves fragment instance and when fragment became invisible, system calls fragment `onDestroyView()` method because view destroyed, but after it system doesn't call method `onDestroy()` because fragment instance saved in backStack and there is reference on fragment instance and it doesn't destroy. And if instance not destroyed system keeps that instance attached to activity and doesn't call `onDetach()` it.

Comment: I don't know why this was disliked. It worked in my case, thanks!